# Jquery Add (SUM) Multiple value from multiple Form element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the form I have...

```
<form>
  <label>Fisrt:</label>
  <select class="first">
    <option value="0">United</option>
    <option value="1">Indi</option>
    <option value="2">Kingdom</option>
  </select>
  <label>Second:</label>
  <select class="second">
    <option value="0">States</option>
    <option value="1">orange</option>
    <option value="2">apple</option>
  </select>

  <input type="text" class="form-control trScr" id="temp" name="temp">
  <input type="text" class="form-control trScr" id="bc" name="bc">

</form>

<div id="total">Total: </div>
```

As you see above, I want to add the numeric value for the dropdown selected with the inserted value for the inputbox. how do i calculate and show the result on div id=total?

Example ..If I select from the dropdown united (0 value) and orange(1 value), And if I insert first and second inputbox respectively(4,2)! I want the result to be 0 + 1 + 4 + 2 = 7. How do i calculate using Jquery? if not Js?

My try...
function calculateSum() {

```
    var sum = 0;
    //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
    $(".trScr").each(function() {
        //add only if the value is number
        if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
            sum += parseFloat(this.value);
      console.log(sum);
        }
    });
    //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
    return sum.toFixed(0);
  }
```

the above show the sum of textbox perfectly, My real problem is how the select can be added with the above code?

Comment: MR.Internet,what you done so far?

Comment: you can do it by trying some stuff at your end and add that effort in your question if you stuck at any point of time. But the main thing is at-least try something

Comment: I was working the whole night with no real progress...let me post some of my code....

Comment: There is no reason to downvote.  We have all been there and struggled and this is an honest question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here was my solution:

```
$('#fm').on('input', function(e){
    let total = Number($('.first').val()) + 
                Number($('.second').val()) + 
                Number($('#temp').val()) + 
                Number($('#bc').val());
    $('#total').text(total);
});
```

fiddle:- https://jsfiddle.net/wr6ympos/3/

Comment: why i get Nan Error? have any idea?

Comment: i added id #fm to your <form>

Comment: if a user enters a character instead of a number into the input fields, Number function will fail and give you NaN.

Comment: please add the following option to the select ...<select class="second">
    <option value="selected">select oen</option>
    <option value="0">States</option>
    <option value="1">orange</option>
    <option value="2">apple</option>
  </select>
you will see the Error NaN.. how do you solve it?

Comment: we are near please help

Comment: Because you are giving a value of 'selected' to the option.

Think about this.  What happens if you do 2+5+'selected'+4?

Comment: You would get 7selected4 most likely, but because I'm wrapping all those with Number() function, Number('selected') makes no sense, thus you get NaN.

Comment: To fix, give value of <option value='4'>select oen</option>

Comment: added another fiddle for you, this code requires a label before each form element, and will tell user to make sure to sanitize their input with what you need, (not text but specifically numbers):

https://jsfiddle.net/wr6ympos/4/

Answer (score 1):

You will need a form button if not want to calculate the total based on `change` event

```js
// adding event to button
document.getElementById('calculate').addEventListener('click', function() {
  // getting value from the two select
  var getFirstSelectVal = document.getElementsByClassName('first')[0].value;
  var getSecondSelectVal = document.getElementsByClassName('second')[0].value
  // getting value from two input box
  var getTempValue = document.getElementById('temp').value;
  var getBCValue = document.getElementById('bc').value;
  // the + sign before the variable is unary operator to convert value to number
  // + +variableName. The first sign s use to sum 
  // using innerHTML to show the value
  document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = +getFirstSelectVal + +getSecondSelectVal + +getTempValue + +getBCValue;
  //console.log(getFirstSelectVal)

})
```

```html
<form>
  <label>Fisrt:</label>
  <select class="first">
    <option value="0">United</option>
    <option value="1">Indi</option>
    <option value="2">Kingdom</option>
  </select>
  <label>Second:</label>
  <select class="second">
    <option value="0">States</option>
    <option value="1">orange</option>
    <option value="2">apple</option>
  </select>

  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="temp" name="temp">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="bc" name="bc">
  <input type="button" value="Calculate" id="calculate">
</form>

<div id="total">Total: </div>
```

Comment: Wrong.  Instead of using change event, use input event.

Comment: @simon i mean change for the `select` elements

Comment: Yes and I'm saying you dont need a button to track the event of the select elements changing.